# using the kernel/cokernel to minimally adjust a homomorphism of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, group-homomorphism

The Kernel and Cokernel of a homomorphism (say of abelian groups) $\varphi : G \to H$ measure how $\varphi$ fails to be injective and surjective respectively.
If the kernel is trivial, then $\varphi$ is injective, and dually for the cokernel. Let's focus on the kernel from here forwards, but I'm interested in related questions for the cokernel.

Checking if the kernel is trivial seems to throw away a lot of information, because we aren't making use of what the kernel *actually is*. 
Obviously we can use information about the kernel more economically by using the isomorphism theorems, but can we use it to minimally adjust $\varphi$?

Say $\varphi : G \to H$ has nontrivial kernel. Can we find a group $H'$ which is somehow closely related to $H$, with a hom $\varphi' : G \to H'$ which is closely related to $\varphi$, such that $\varphi'$ is injective? If so, can this "closely related"-ness be formalized as a universal property?

Edit:

Using $\varphi$ we can view $G$ as being "almost a subgroup" of $H$, where we might have to fudge some of the multiplication table to make $G$ fit. This fudging is measured by the kernel of $\varphi$. Say $\varphi$ *isn't* surjective. Then is there a way to extend $H$ in some minimal fashion in order to faithfully witness $G$ as a subgroup?

Edit 2:

To answer the "what have you tried" comment, let $C = H / Im (\varphi)$ be the cokernel of $\varphi$. Then $H' = C \times G$ is a new group which is similar to $H$ into which $G$ embeds. However, if there were relations between elements in the cokernel and elements in the image of $\varphi$, it feels like these may have been clobbered by this change. Is there a better construction which preserves more of the original structure of $H$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $\varphi': G/\ker \varphi \to H' = H$  given by $\varphi'(\bar{x}) = \varphi(x)$ should be well-defined and injective since $\varphi(\bar{x}) = 0 \implies x \in \ker f \implies \bar{x} = 0 \pmod{ \ker f}$.  $\varphi$ induces the $\varphi'$ so that's how they're related.

Comment: the problem is that injectivity is controlled completely by the kernel, which has as a target the codomain, hence you have no chance if you do not manipulate $G$. in the end it seems like you want to consider the coimage-image morphism$$\widehat{\varphi}: G/\ker(\varphi) \to \mathrm{im}(\varphi)$$ as this is the minimal isomorphism corresponding to $\varphi$, which together with kernel and cokernel completely describes the morphism (as we are, hopefully, in an abelian category).

Comment: In addition, if you are in an even nicer context in which every short exact sequence splits (such as vector spaces instead of groups) then you may find a subobject $X$ of the domain $G$ which is isomorphic to $G/\ker(\varphi)$ and a subobject $Y$ of the codomain $H$ which is isomorphic to $H/\mathrm{im}(f)$ and then look at $G\cong \ker(\varphi)\oplus X$, $H\cong Y\oplus \mathrm{im}(f)$ and $\varphi$ substituted by $\widetilde{\varphi}:X\to \mathrm{im}(f)$. But this is a very particular situation

Comment: Judging by the comments, perhaps I was unclear. If $\varphi$ is not surjective, then G is "almost a subgroup" of H, where the "almost" is measured by the Kernel. Can we extend H somehow in order to render $\varphi$ injective? I've updated the question to make this point of view more explicit.