# Rendering a Homomorphism Injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, fiber-bundles

Over a year ago now I asked [a bad question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243528/using-the-kernel-cokernel-to-minimally-adjust-a-homomorphism-of-abelian-groups). Recently I was reminded of this question, though in the year of growth I've had as a mathematician and MSE user, I have gained the language to make precise what was once a glimmer of an idea. I apologize for reposting, but I think this is sufficiently changed to warrant an entirely new question.

Given a group hom $\varphi : G \to H$, we can look at its mono-epi factorization $\varphi = \iota \pi$:

[image: mono-epi factorization]

Here $N = \text{Ker }\varphi$ is the obstruction to $\varphi$'s injectivity, and it is natural to ask if we can extend $H$ by $N$ in a way that is compatible with $\varphi$. However, I think this question is best phrased geometrically.

We can view $G$ as a bundle over $G/N$, where each fibre is isomorphic to $N$. Then since $G/N$ includes into $H$, our question becomes this: Can we *extend* this bundle structure from $G/N$ to all of $H$ in a way that is compatible with the group structure of $G$?

Ideally, we should end with a commutative square of the following sort:

[image: the desired extension]

This has to do with solving an extension problem

[image: the extension problem, made explicit]

and I suspect this will require other geometric tools, such as group cohomology.

Is this problem solvable? Even special cases would be of interest. Have people considered this problem before? I would be happy for references to papers or books.

---

Thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Note added in edit: I misunderstood the question the first time around---see comments. I left the original here so everything still makes sense.

OK, this looks like you are trying to define a semidirect product. The easiest way to describe such a thing is that the short exact sequence defining $G$ splits, i.e., the map $\iota$ above has an inverse $\theta$ so that the composition is the identity on $G/N$. This allows you to extend the multiplication on $H$ to one on $G$, i.e., embed $H$ as a subgroup of $G$.

If $N$ is abelian, this is equivalent to the vanishing of the second cohomology group of $H$ on $N$, via conjugation action. The same holds for general $N$ but you need to use non-abelian cohomology.

Edit: Let $G$ be a central extension of a simple group $X$ by a group $Z$, so an element of $H^2(Z,G)$ essentially. The group $X$ can be embedded in another simple group $Y$ such that there is no non-split extension of $Y$ by $Z$. An easy example is alternating groups. The Schur multiplier (largest central extension) of $A_7$ is cyclic of order $6$, whereas for $A_8$ it's cyclic of order $2$. Thus the group $3\cdot A_7$ cannot be extended to a group $3\cdot A_8$.

Comment: This answer applies only in the case that $G$ splits $\varphi$ as a semidirect product _and_ $\varphi$ is surjective onto $H$. Then, as you've implicitly said, we can use the identity function on $G$ as the desired injective map. I'll admit, I had not considered this special case, and I appreciate you bringing it up! It's a good example. I'm looking for something more general out of an accepted answer, though.

Comment: Aha. So the question splits into two parts. The first is, you must have a semidirect product, else it doesn't work even when $\phi$ is surjective. So we may assume that, and now you have two groups $X$ and $Y$, and a common subgroup $H$ of both of them, and you want to know if there's a group $G$ containing both $X$ and $Y$ and such that $X$ and $Y$ intersect in $H$. The answer is 'yes', it's the *free product with amalgamation*. It is infinite. You possibly want finite quotients of this, and these are looked at all the time in group theory, called *amalgams*.

Comment: Would you please post that as an answer, and provide a proof (or reference) for the claim that $G$ must be a semidirect product? If you could also elaborate on solving this problem with amalgams, that would be fantastic! I am familiar with them only through Algebraic Topology, so they didn't even come to my mind for this problem.

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood you the first time. I originally thought you wanted to extend the $H$-action to the action of some group that contains both $H$ and $G$, which is what I described. What you actually want to to construct some group $\tilde G$ such that $\tilde G$ contains $G$, $N$ is normal in $\tilde G$, and $\tilde G/N$ is isomorphic to $H$, for any $H$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H$. This cannot be done in general. I will give an example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! It's a good counterexample to show that this cannot always be done. Do you know of any conditions which allow it to be done?

Comment: Look at the much easier question of whether a non-split extension of $G$ by $N$ splits upon restriction to a subgroup $H$ of $G$, There are examples where $N$ is abelian, where $H^2(G,N)$ and $H^2(H,N)$ are isomorphic, but the restriction map is zero. Thus there is a non-split extension of $G$ by $N$ that splits upon restriction to $H$, and conversely a non-split extension of $H$ by $N$ that therefore cannot extend to an extension of $G$ by $N$. The ones I have worked with in the past came from groups of Lie type acting on modules, and aren't so easy to describe. There are likely easier ones.